# Is it OK to redirect ASP files to HTML files? How long should the redirects be in place?

Tags: html, redirects, 301-redirect, asp

I need to redirect a big stack of URLs from old `.asp` to `.html` file extensions.

We are working on a windows server therefore I think I can use the *web.config* file to set these redirects.  I am also considering about the option of placing the redirect in each of the old files instead to make the transition a bit safer.

Is it safe to merge the HTML files with the ASP files? If so, how long should I keep the old files with the redirect on them?

Comment: Make sure your redirects are **301** and not _302_ (as is sometimes default).

Answer (score 1):

If you are changing your URLs from `.asp` to `.html`, then you absolutely should use redirects.

Your redirects should stay in place indefinitely.    It is very difficult to change every last link to your pages.   Even if you were able to change all the inbound links, Googlebot will still come visit your old URLs for years and years.